# Proving the asymptotically limit of the ratio between the exponential of a function and its derivative

Tags: limits, asymptotics, exponential-function

I want to prove (or give a counterexample) the following limit:

$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} | \frac{\exp(g(x))}{g'(x)}| = \infty,
$$

where $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous and differentiable for all $x>0$. And let $ 1 \prec \log(x) \prec g(x)$ (asymptotically bigger).

I have tried several functions and the limit seems to hold for all of them, but I cannot find a general proof. I would really appreciate some help :)

**NOTE**

$A(x) \prec B(x)$ if $\lim_{x\to\infty} | \frac{B(x)}{A(x)}| = \infty$.

Comment: What about the case $g=x^2(2+\sin(e^{x^3}))$? The question comes down to the behavior of $e^{-x^3}/\cos(e^{x^3})$ for large $x$. Does it have a well-defined limit?

Answer (score 0):

If we consider only functions that are the solutions of time invariant first order differential equations $y'=f(y)$, with $f>0$ and increasing, then I think the answer is yes.

$y'=y^{1+\epsilon}$ actually diverges in finite time for any $\epsilon>0$. This means that any $f(y)$ that doesn't cause $y$ to diverge must be eventually bounded above by all $y^{1+\epsilon}$.

The limit you wrote becomes $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{e^y}{f(y)}$$

Since $f$ can't be that much more than linear, it is easy for the exponential to overpower it.

I think this is a little narrow in scope -- not all functions can be written this way -- but it does actually cover a lot of cases.